# Excel keeps crashing when I set a certain worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

The workbook keeps crashing when it gets to the

`Set wsEDF = Worksheets("edf master")` line.  I have tried to delete the sheet and then reinstate it and the same thing happens.  Am a bit confused.

```
Sub CopyGroups()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wsMarex = Worksheets("marex master")
Set wsMQ = Worksheets("macquarie master")
Set wsEDF = Worksheets("edf master")
```

There is an end sub plus all the variables were declared at the top.  Also at one point the macros worked fine.  So have gone back to an old version and will look at changing that based on some advice below.

Comment: Double check the sheet name, looking for a space before or after, or maybe 2 spaces in between.

Comment: What error is the compiler throwing?

Comment: @Jarom I bet it's the runtime throwing, not the compiler. Unless OP's code is indeed missing an `End Sub` token. That would be run-time error 9, subscript out of range, because no sheet exists in the active workbook by the name `edf master`. Could also be a compiler error if `Option Explicit` is specified, given how none of these variables are declared anywhere.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Great points, it looks like you are correct.  Thanks for the thoughts!

Comment: It sometimes does work.  So definitely named correctly.  I also declare my variables at the top of the code under option explicit.  I will play around again and see if it works.  It just crashes and doesn't come up with an error per se just says Microsoft Excel has stopped working.  Not a VBA error.

Comment: Sorry I haven't put all the code as its a lot of code and has crashed before I even get any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no sheet named `edf master` in the active workbook. [Watch for whitespace (leading and/or trailing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929981/vba-excel-keeps-crashing-when-i-set-a-certain-worksheet#comment82828537_47929981).

If the active workbook is `ThisWorkbook` (i.e. the workbook that contains the code that's running), then you don't need any of this.

Look at the *Project Explorer* (Ctrl+R). Under "Microsoft Excel Objects" you'll find a class module for every single sheet in your workbook. Click one, then hit F4 to display the *Properties* box.

In the sheet's properties, you'll see it has a `(Name)` property, which is probably saying something like `Sheet1`. Change it to something meaningful, e.g. `MarexMasterSheet`, or `MacquarieMasterSheet`, or `EDFMasterSheet`.

Then you don't need `wsMarex`, `wsMQ` and `wsEDF` anymore - they're already declared for you, as global-scope `Worksheet` instances. So, say the next line of code was this:

```
Debug.Print wsMarex.CodeName
```

Now you can do this instead:

```
Debug.Print MarexMasterSheet.CodeName
```

Comment: There is definitely a sheet called EDF Master with the same spelling the error I get is Microsoft Excel has stopped working and the whole thing crashes.

Comment: Also when I call the sheet "EDF" and make sure the spelling is the same in the code it still crashes.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean about renaming the sheets.  I have never done that before.  But I think the whole sheet is unstable as it keeps crashing when I try and change the code so may start again from scratch / the old version that used to work.